# Kong response-transformer-advanced plugin

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin

I have written the below code in Config.Transform.Functions (response-transformer-advanced plugin)
I hard coded for element ( data.statements[1])…how can I make dynamic ( data.statements JSON array. Loop through all cardnum in data.statements[ 1…n ]). I tried put lua script loop but the above Kong plugin is not accepting the script. Please help me with looping of the below program which need to executed in Kong.

```
return function (data)
    local s= data.statements[1].cardnum
    local x= s:sub(10 )
    data.statements[1].cardnum= “********”…x
return data end
```

Comment: Can you paste down what error Kong return to you? Did you upload the script using Admin API or paste it into Kong Manager?

Comment: you have … in your code, I think you want `..`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the merge operator and string delimiter

Lua merge operator is `..` please use `"`

In your code your have `…`, `“` and `”`

```lua
return function (data)
    local s= data.statements[1].cardnum
    local x= s:sub(10 )
    data.statements[1].cardnum= "********"..x
return data end
```

Comment: My previous code itself working for single value...I want loop through for multiple values like data.statements[i] by using loop. I tried LUA script but it's not working

Comment: return function (data) 

 
   local i = 1
 for key, value in pairs(data.statements) do

     local s= data.statements[i].cardnum   
  local x= s:sub(10 )    
  data.statements[i].cardnum=  "********"..x    
           i = i + 1
     end
 return data end

Comment: I am getting the below error

Comment: schema violation (config.transform: { functions = { "Error parsing function: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/kong-lua-sandbox.lua:151: [string \"return function (data) ...\"]:1: '=' or 'in' expected near '<eof>'", "Error parsing function: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/kong-lua-sandbox.lua:151: [string \"value in pairs(data.statements) do ...\"]:1: '=' expected near 'in'" } })

Comment: Please edit you question with those details